# Is it normal that the left bond is sloped, and can it be made vertical?

Tags: chemfig

When I tried to show the C and H atoms in the ring of cyclohexane, the left bond became sloped.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(------)}
\chemfig{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-C)}
\chemfig{CH2*6(-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2)}
\chemfig{\ce{CH2}*6(-\ce{CH2}-CH(-\ce{C3H7})-\ce{CH2}-CH(-\ce{C2H5})-\ce{CH2}-\ce{CH2})}
\chemfig{*6(--(-\ce{C3H7})--(-\ce{C2H5})--)}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to show the atoms, and have an accurate ring?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Is it normal…” – at least it's to be expected. Here's section 10.5 *Rings and groups of atoms* of the `chemfig` manual:

> Some care must be taken with rings when one or more vertices are made up of groups of atoms:
>
> ```
> \chemfig{AB*5(-CDE-F-GH-I-)}
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> In order for the ring to have a regular shape, it is necessary to
>   override the `chemfig` mechanism which automatically calculates the
>   departure and arrival atoms of bonds. Here, C-F and F-G must be
>   connected by using the optional argument of these bonds:
>
> ```
> \chemfig{AB*5(-CDE-[,,1]F-[,,,1]GH-I-)}
> ```
>
> [image]

You can use the same in your case.

The meaning of those optional arguments is explained in section 5 *Departure and arrival atoms*.

> One may sometimes want the bond partners to be atoms other than those
>   determined by ChemFig. The departure and arrival atoms can be set with
>   the optional bond argument by writing:
>
> ```
> [,,<integer 1>,<integer 2>]
> ```
>
> where `<integer 1>` and `<integer 2>` are the numbers of the desired
>   departure and arrival atoms. These atoms must exist, otherwise an
>   error message will be given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{H_2C*6(-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-H_2C-[,,2])}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remark:

If you want to use `mhchem` with `chemfig` have a look at this article from Joseph: [Exploring `chemfig`: Customizing appearance](https://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/).

Comment: Argh! Got it - there was no need to use Mhchem in Chemfig. It also took forever to compile. Once removed `\ce{}` everything fixed itself and compilation time is a fraction of what it used to be!

Answer (score 4):

Enclose the molecular nodes with braces `{ }` .

```
\documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \chemfig{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-C)}
    \chemfig{CH_2*6(-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-{CH_2}-CH_2)}
    \chemfig{{CH_2}*6(-{CH_2}-CH(-{C_3H_7})-{CH_2}-{CH}(-{C_2H_5})-{CH_2}-{CH_2})}
    \chemfig{*6(--(-{C_3H_7})--(-{C_2H_5})--)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, great, and the only group that requires the braces is the CH group that ethyl group is attached to! `\chemfig{\ce{CH2}*6(-\ce{CH2}-CH(-\ce{C3H7})-\ce{CH2}-{CH}(-\ce{C2H5})-\ce{CH2}-\ce{CH2})}`

Comment: The bonds should end at the `C` and not at the `H` or somewhere in between!